# ruby regexp - how to search for one word but not if another exists (in url/uri).?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.8.7

How can I do a regexp in ruby 1.8 that matches:

```
/my_dir/1/file
```

but not if I have:

```
/my_dir/1/deeper_stuff/file
```

So far I have

```
 source_string = '/my_dir/1/index.html.erb'

 /^\/my_dir/.match(source_string)
```

for the initial match, how do I add the second disqualifier for `/deeper_stuff` ?

so that

```
 source_string = '/my_dir/1/deeper_stuff/'
```

gets excluded.

Comment: Not related but IMHO `source_string =~ /^\/my_dir(?!.*deeper_stuff)/` is better idea (I've used @kirilloid regexp).

Answer (score 7):

Negative look-ahead: `/^\/my_dir(?!.*deeper_stuff)/.match(source_string)`

Answer (score 1):

`/^/my_dir/\w*/\w+.\S*/.match(source_string)` should work assuming all files end with a period and then some extension (to include multiple extensions such as `.html.erb`).

This works by searching for `/my_dir/` followed by any number of word characters (letter, number, underscore) followed a forward-slash. This matches the next directory. Then we look for one or more word characters followed by a period followed by any number of non-whitespace characters. Thus, `/my_dir/deeper_stuff/file.html.erb` will be excluded because the additional directory causes the regex to not match.

Answer (score 1):

RE = Regexp.new("^/my_dir/1(/.+)?/file$")

def is_file(dir) 
   (m = RE.match(dir)) && !m[1] ? "match" : "no match"
end

puts is_file("/my_file/1") #=> no match
puts is_file("/my_dir/1/file") #=> match 
puts is_file("/my_dir/1/deeper_stuff/file") #=> no match
puts is_file("/my_dir/1/deeper/stuff/file") #=> no match